# On the timeweb server, django-ckeditor does not work in the admin panel

Tags: python, django

on server:

Python == 3.10

Django == 4.2.9

django-ckeditor == 5.9.0 - 6.7.0

the editor was installed according to the instructions https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#section-9 there is no point in rewriting

my files:

**models.py**

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
...
education = RichTextField(verbose_name='Education')
...
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
     'ckeditor'
]

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/.../public_html/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

after changing the code I started getting an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'dir')
at Object.d (VM1137 ckeditor.js:260:54)    
at w (VM1137 ckeditor.js:261:181)    
at Array.y (VM1137 ckeditor.js:261:336)    
at z (VM1137 ckeditor.js:261:420)    
at A.CKEDITOR.env.ie.f.$.onerror (VM1137 ckeditor.js:262:429)
```

how can this be solved?

I tried changing the paths and reinstalling the application, to no avail.

the following paths also appear in the console:
experts.umiic.ru/admin/experts/expert/4/change/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/config.js?t=N5UC
experts.umiic.ru/admin/experts/expert/4/change/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css?t=N5UC
experts.umiic.ru/admin/experts/expert/4/change/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/lang/ru.js?t=N5UC

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` setting. It shouldn't be necessary to set it; and if it is, it should be set to a URL path (for example `/static/ckeditor/.../`) not to a filesystem path.

Comment: I deleted this line but the result is the same, what’s also confusing is that I have ?t=N5UC added to some files experts.umiic.ru/admin/experts/expert/4/change/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css?t=N5UC